# How to manage database connections?

Tags: architecture, d

Where is a good place to hold a database connection?  I'm going to use in a bunch of different places, so it's be nice to be able to access it from somewhere and not have to always pass it around.

Comment: Don't hold it. Close it as soon as you can and use a connection pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All my applications have "ApplicationModel" class/struct where, depending on number of DB connections, I either have a single member variable (in the case I deal only with a single connection), or I have a simple array of DB connnections. Naturally, ApplicationModel has accessor for it.

I pass around a reference to the ApplicationModel in constructors of those objects that need it. Alternative is to make ApplicationModel a Singleton with the same functionality. - Then you do not need to pass it around... I stopped using Singleton for this purpose not so long ago as I find [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prolly just use a static associative array in an accessor class (like a singleton), with the key being the DB connection string and the value being the connection object.

Answer (score 0):

Since your questions is `Architecture` tagged, I can advise you to consider also the usage of [Flyweight design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/flyweight-design-pattern). It will allow immutable classes to use preconstructed instances, or to cache instances as they’re constructed, and dispense them repeatedly to avoid creating unnecessary duplicate objects.

> use in a bunch of different places

It can greatly improve performance if equivalent objects are requested often, especially if they are expensive to create. If this is your case.

Also I use [Command design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern), especially when I have to deal couple DB connections.